# weak convergence implies boundedness.

Tags: real-analysis

I have these in books without proof, mostly as a corollary. I was wondering if I could get a proof.

Suppose $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f_ng dx = \int_0^1 fg dx$$ for all $g\in L^2(0,1)$,  where $f_n, f \in L^2(0,1)$.  Then there exists a constant $K$ such that $\|f_n\|_{L^2} \leq K \lt \infty$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Banach-Steinhaus tells us that a family of linear functionals on a Banach space is either unbounded on a dense $G_\delta$ set or is uniformly bounded in norm.  Since this family converges weakly we have for any $g \in L^2$ that $\sup_n \langle f_n , g \rangle < \infty$ and therefore the family of functionals is uniformly bounded in norm.

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Josh on which part?

Comment: The conclusion.

Comment: @Josh Banach-Steinhaus (aka the uniform boundedness principle) says that exactly one of two things is true: either we can find a lot of functions (in particular, one exists) in $L^2$ for which $\sup_n \langle f_n , g\rangle = \infty$ _or_ $\|f_n\| \leq C$ for some uniform constant $C$.  But the $f_n$ sequence converges weakly, so that for any $g$ $\lim_{n \to \infty} \langle f_n , g \rangle$ exists.  A convergent sequence of reals is bounded and so in particular we know that the set of $g$ for which $\sup_n \langle f_n , g \rangle = \infty$ is empty, so we must have a uniform norm bound.

Comment: What does the symbol $\langle f_n , g\rangle$  mean?

Comment: @Josh it's inner product notation for $\int f_n (x) g(x) dx$.  It's fairly comon to write $\langle T , f \rangle$ for the evaluation of the functional $T$ on an element $f$ of a Banach space.

Comment: oh okay. Thanks.